# How do I use a pod name in a volume mount?

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to specify a `hostPath` volume so that it includes the pod's name? For example, something like the following:

```
  volumes:
    - name: vol-test
      hostPath:
        path: /basedir/$(POD_NAME)
        type: Directory
```

Simply using /basedir directly and then have the pod itself query for its name and create the directory doesn't satisfy my needs: I specifically want to map each of my containers' /tmp folders to specific volumes.

I know that something similar works with `valueFrom` for environment variables (see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/)), but so far I haven't been able to find anything similar for volumes.

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set it as an env var first via valueFrom and then certain fields understand `$(FOO)` as an env var reference to be interpolated at runtime.

EDIT: And `path` is not one of those fields. But `subPathExpr` is.

Comment: I tried that by itself and it didn't work. The important twist is to use subpath expressions as documented here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath-with-expanded-environment-variables. If you update your answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I elided that with "certain fields" :) Only a few support it like `command` and `subPathExpr`.